# Getting all files from a folder and opening them onclick

Tags: php, file

I am reading a folder with glob() function in php

```
foreach (glob("folder/*.*") as $filename) {
    echo $filename."<br />"
}
```

My folder contains three kind of files pdf, image, videos. What I need here is to make a link for each file and open them on click.

How can I achieve this, any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean with open them? Do you want to load the video in the browser or what?

Comment: <a href='path + $filename' target='_blank' ?

Comment: Yes I need to open the pdf or video on browser itself. If I can show them within my application in any div it would be great.

Comment: In what format are your videos? mp4?

Comment: Yes, they are in mp4 format

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

(This creates you a list of all files which you can click on it and you get it opened in the new tab)

```
$files = glob("folder/*.*");

foreach($files as $file)    
    echo "<a href='" . $file . "' target='_blank'>" . $file . "</a><br />";
```